# Explanation for the GPS “special message” field

Tags: gps

In the [GPS specification](https://www.gps.gov/technical/icwg/IS-GPS-200M.pdf) (p124) there is a facility for the satellite to send a “special message”. The content is “at the discretion of Operating Command” but is anyone aware of any statement of how this is actually used, or has someone reverse-engineered it? I’ve seen data present, but before I put in effort to more systematically collect it, I would like to know whether someone has already found out what it means.

**Update 2023-09-26:** I've been recording special messages for three weeks, and here's what I've received, with the time being when it was first received (UTC).

```
2023-09-05T00:15:36 43+26SV-G"-S6+DSK3H85F
2023-09-10T00:08:06 NBBK.KQO-C75R1FUY6BJZ6
2023-09-11T00:05:36 0DKNSOM"X"MI:R.5UBZTZI
2023-09-17T00:08:06 -NM"UJDX°ME+HS-7CQ+/S/
2023-09-24T00:08:06 YKXW/Q'°+RIDN'O7Z723TF
2023-09-25T00:05:36 MUA9"LG.'0II-'080"5NIH
2023-09-26T00:03:06 /Q"RNM-C62ELZH1QHD0IDC
```

Some observations:

- There's no obvious structure to the messages
- I receive about 200 messages per day
- Even though the characters are 8-bit, the messages sent appear to respect the restricted character set in the specification
- All satellites (that I can see) send the same message
- The message changes at midnight (maybe UTC, maybe GPS time)
- The time between message updates varies; from what I've seen between 1 and 7 days

Answer (score 1):

The only other reference I've ever seen is in the RTCM [spec](https://www.sigidwiki.com/images/6/66/Rtcm-sc104-transmission-characteristics-of-marine-differential-gps-stations.pdf) and this just describes it as a null terminated 90 character ASCII field, with parity.  The example is "HELLO".  I have not see real world data, but then I haven't looked.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I've started to collect data, though the message is the same for all satellites and changes only every few days, so I don't have much. Here's what I've recorded so far: `43+26SV-G"-S6+DSK3H85F`, `NBBK.KQO-C75R1FUY6BJZ6`, `0DKNSOM"X"MI:R.5UBZTZI`, `-NM"UJDX°ME+HS-7CQ+/S/`.

Comment: I had seen a mention in a chat long ago that these messages might be used to update decryption keys for the secure precision GPS channel used by the military.  No idea if that is right.

Comment: It’s not implausible. The lack of any pattern is consistent with something cryptography-related. Perhaps they retrofitted key rotation on the W-code, but there’s basically nothing public about it to verify. Even if I could find the W-code with a high gain antenna, I doubt the generator key could be discovered to check. If the special message was used as key rotation, however, I’d expect a consistent frequency of update but I haven’t found any pattern there.